# Auto Layout Constraint Conflict in SwiftUI When Tapping TextField

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, autolayout

I am developing an iOS app using SwiftUI and have encountered an Auto Layout constraint conflict issue that appears when tapping on a TextField within a LoginView. I've tried several troubleshooting steps but haven't been able to resolve it.

Error Message:

```
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000021298b0 'accessoryView.bottom' _UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x10460dd10.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView:0x1059220e0.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000217a620 'assistantHeight' SystemInputAssistantView.height == 45   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x10591ce60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000217d090 'assistantView.bottom' SystemInputAssistantView.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView:0x1059220e0.top   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x10591ce60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000217d040 'assistantView.top' V:[_UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x10460dd10]-(0)-[SystemInputAssistantView]   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x10591ce60 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000217d040 'assistantView.top' V:[_UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x10460dd10]-(0)-[SystemInputAssistantView]   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x10591ce60 )>
```

This error appears in the console when I click on the TextField in my LoginView while running the code on a simulation. The app doesn't crash, but the console indicates there is a constraint conflict related to the keyboard. Here's my LoginView:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = LoginViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image("logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 100)
                
                VStack {
                    TextField("Enter your email", text: $viewModel.email)
                        .autocapitalization(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.none/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .modifier(TextFieldModifier())
                    
                    SecureField("Enter your password", text: $viewModel.password)
                        .modifier(TextFieldModifier())
                }
                
                Button {
                    print("Show forgot password")
                } label: {
                    Text("Forgot Password")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .padding(.top)
                        .padding(.trailing, 20)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                
                Button {
                    Task { try await viewModel.signIn() }
                } label: {
                    Text("Login")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 360, height: 44)
                        .background(Color(.black))
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }
                .padding(.vertical)
                
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) - 40, height: 0.5)
                        
                    Text("OR")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) - 40, height: 0.5)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                
                HStack {
                    Image("facebook_logo")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    
                    Text("Continue with Facebook")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBlue))
                }
                .padding(.top, 8)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Divider()
                
                NavigationLink {
                    AddEmailView()
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                } label: {
                    HStack (spacing: 3) {
                        Text("Don't have an account?")
                        
                        Text("Sign Up")
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    }
                    .font(.footnote)
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 16)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    LoginView()
}
```

And my TextFieldModifier:

```
struct TextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) ->some View {
        content
            .font(.subheadline)
            .padding(12)
            .background(Color(.systemGray6))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding(.horizontal, 24)
            .padding(.top)
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. What could be causing this Auto Layout constraint conflict in a SwiftUI app?
2. Are there any known issues with SwiftUI's TextField and keyboard interactions that might lead to such constraints issues?
3. Any suggestions on how to debug or resolve this constraint conflict?

Attempts to Resolve:

1. I've checked the TextFieldModifier for any potential issues but it seems standard.
2. I've tried simplifying the view by removing other elements, but the issue persists.
3. The issue seems to occur regardless of the simulator device or iOS version I use.

Comment: Common issue. Seems safe to ignore.

Answer (score 3):

This error is a System error caused by SecureField.
You make nothing wrong here and your app should be okay.
I believe that Apple will fix this soon and update us.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a relief -- it's been a headscratcher trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: the same issue with drawing the bottom button having 2 or more TextField-s in a VStack, one of them is .secureField.
Upvoting the question and the answer.

Also there is a thread on Apple`s developer forum adressing the same behaviour. or similar one.